# How to include a space character with grep?

Tags: command-line, grep, regex

I have a file named example

```
$ cat example

kali.pdf
linux.pdf
ubuntu.pdf
example.pdf.
this.pdf
grep .pdf
```

and when I use `grep` to get the line that has a space before `.pdf`, I can't seem to get it.

```
grep *.pdf example
```

returns nothing, (I want to say, "grep, match zero or more spaces before `.pdf`", but no result)

and if I use:

```
grep i*.pdf example

kali.pdf
linux.pdf
ubuntu.pdf
example.pdf.
this.pdf
grep .pdf
```

all lines return, because I'm saying "grep, match me `i` one or zero times, ok."

and lastly:

```
grep " *.pdf" example
```

no result returns

For this sample, I want to see

```
grep .pdf
```

as output

What is wrong with my thought?

Answer (score 43, accepted):

Make sure you quote your expression.

```
$ grep ' \.pdf' example
grep .pdf
```

Or if there might be multiple spaces (we can't use `*` as this will match the cases where there are no preceding spaces)

```
grep ' \+\.pdf' example
```

`+` means "one or more of the preceding character". In BRE you need to escape it with `\` to get this special function, but you can use ERE instead to avoid this

```
grep -E ' +\.pdf' example
```

You can also use `\s` in `grep` to mean a space

```
grep '\s\+\.pdf' example
```

We should escape literal `.` because in regex `.` means any character, unless it's in a character class.

Comment: You were the first who noticed that the last line had space.

Comment: @Pilot6 thanks. The question was a little confusingly written :)

Comment: There should be some badge for the first who understood the question ;-)

Comment: @Zanna, is there anything wrong to go anytime egrep in this cases? egrep always gets you advantage...

Comment: @solfish `egrep` is (in terms of regex style, afaik) the same as `grep -E`, and I *believe* we are meant to use the latter - `egrep` etc are supposedly deprecated in favour of `grep`'s flags